# How do you pull first 100 characters of a string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I am looking for a way to pull the first 100 characters from a string variable to put in another variable for printing.

Is there a function that can do this easily?

For example:

```
$string1 = "I am looking for a way to pull the first 100 characters from a string variable to put in another variable for printing.";
$string2 = 100charfunction($string1);
print $string2
```

To get:

```
I am looking for a way to pull the first 100 characters from a string vari
```

Comment: Better question would be : How do you pull / select first n characters from a string?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

```
$small = substr($big, 0, 100);
```

For [String Manipulation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) here is a page with a lot of function that might help you in your future work.

Comment: there is problem on returning Arabic text, as they are words with combined letters if the second parameter(100) is not at end of Arabic words on the last while counting 100  it will return null. for that we will use(mb_substr($big,0,100)

Answer (score 40):

You could use substr, I guess:

```
$string2 = substr($string1, 0, 100);
```

or mb_substr for multi-byte strings:

```
$string2 = mb_substr($string1, 0, 100);
```

You could create a function wich uses this function and appends for instance `'...'` to indicate that it was shortened. (I guess there's allready a hundred similar replies when this is posted...)

Answer (score 38):

A late but useful answer, 
PHP has a function specifically for this purpose.

[mb_strimwidth](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php)

```
$string = mb_strimwidth($string, 0, 100);
$string = mb_strimwidth($string, 0, 97, '...'); //optional characters for end
```

Comment: Topical to this answer: [Truncate a multibyte String to n chars](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2154220/2943403)

Answer (score 24):

```
$x = '1234567';

echo substr ($x, 0, 3);  // outputs 123

echo substr ($x, 1, 1);  // outputs 2

echo substr ($x, -2);    // outputs 67

echo substr ($x, 1);     // outputs 234567

echo substr ($x, -2, 1); // outputs 6
```

Comment: Thank you.  That sums up the variables of the substr() function nicely!

Comment: I have `128.82` in a string and I want to separate `100` and `28.82`

Answer (score 21):

try this function

```
function summary($str, $limit=100, $strip = false) {
    $str = ($strip == true)?strip_tags($str):$str;
    if (strlen ($str) > $limit) {
        $str = substr ($str, 0, $limit - 3);
        return (substr ($str, 0, strrpos ($str, ' ')).'...');
    }
    return trim($str);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without php internal functions:

```
function charFunction($myStr, $limit=100) {    
    $result = "";
    for ($i=0; $i<$limit; $i++) {
        $result .= $myStr[$i];
    }
    return $result;    
}

$string1 = "I am looking for a way to pull the first 100 characters from a string variable to put in another variable for printing.";

echo charFunction($string1);
```