# Breaking the string in certain number of characters

Tags: php

I am looking for the shortest, elegant way to break the unicode string in to certain number of character.

I am having the div enter code herewith different language strings. I am breaking the string after certain number of characters. But for capital and small letters in English there was UI distortion.

I am looking for some workaround to break the string uniform way for any Unicode or capital character or numbers so UI remains intact.

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>test </title>
<style>
  .contri-title
{
float:left;
width:625px;
background-color:#fff0f0;
}

}
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="contri-title bottom-part" id="art_title">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
<br>
<div class="contri-title bottom-part" id="art_title">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `php`? Are you looking for a PHP "hard wrap" or a CSS "soft wrap"? It appears the latter is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this with PHP (like it was tagged) you can use

- [`wordwrap`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) — Wraps a string to a given number of characters

Example from Manual:

```
$text = "A very long woooooooooooord.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 8, "\n", true);
echo "$newtext\n";
```

outputs

```
A very
long
wooooooo
ooooord.
```

I am not sure if this supports multibyte strings though, so you can also have a look at

- [Truncate multibyte string to n chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154220/truncate-a-multibyte-string-to-n-chars)

and adjust the solution to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Add following property in your CSS class

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

Comment: Not very uniformly supported, but might be the answer. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap