# Regex and PHP: adding ellipsis after X number of chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Should be fairly simple for someone who knows regex. I am unfortunately not among those in the know.

How can one append ellipsis to anything over 27 chars in the below example, so that the fourth link listed will appear as `http://iamanextremely.com/long/lin`?

```
<?php

$input = <<<EOF
http://www.example.com/
http://example.com
www.example.com
http://iamanextremely.com/long/link/so/I/will/be/trimmed/down/a/bit/so/i/dont/mess/up/text/wrapping.html
EOF;

$output = preg_replace("/(http:\/\/|(www\.))(([^\s<]{4,27})[^(\s|,)<]*)/",
'<a href="http://$2$3" rel="nofollow">http://$2$4</a>', $input);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate a multibyte String to n chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154220/truncate-a-multibyte-string-to-n-chars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace_callback` to apply a callback to all matched urls. In the callback you can make stuff as fancy as you wish.

```
$output = preg_replace_callback('#(http://|www\\.)[^\\s<]+[^\\s<,.]#i',
                                'trimlong',$input);

function trimlong($match)
{
    $url = $match[0];
    $disp = $url;
    if ( strlen($disp) > 24 ) $disp = substr($disp,0,24)."...";
    return "<a href=\"$url\">$disp</a>";
}
```

(ps. I just took your regexp to start with, I don't think matching a url should be that cumbersome.)

Comment: This seems to be taking any word after the link and placing that in the link as well. Any thoughts on how to change that?

Comment: Yes, fix that regexp. I don't know what you are trying to do, but just matching `http://` and then all but some chars (whitespace or tag openings) will do fine I guess. You may want to match the last character not to be in `[,.]` as well, in case the urls are embedded in natural text.

Comment: @Josh: done. Matches anywthing starting with `http://` OR `www.`, followed by all but whitespace or `<`, ending in all but whitespace, `<`, `.` or `,`.

Comment: Oh, you updated with a trailing `#i` instead of `/i`. Any reason why?

Comment: @Josh: I did some last-minute modifications, for you to understand things better: The first char used will be the "delimiter" which I made `#`, so the `http://` part doesn't become `http:\/\/`. I doubled the other `\` chars, for in theory they could be read as escaped chars (like `\n` is). `\\` boils down to a single `\` once it reaches `preg_replace_callback()`.

Comment: @mvds Ah, I gotcha. Thanks for the updates and the explanations. I appreciate them, especially since the trailing whitespace wasn't working previously.

Comment: @Josh: The `#` chars delimit beginning and end of the pattern (a relic from Perl - which is what the `p` in `preg_` refers to). The `i` modifier tells to ignore case for this pattern. There are several other modifiers, but `i` is the most common one.

Comment: @mvds What element in this is now causing the trailing whitespace to be picked up? Just curious.

Comment: @Josh I don't think it should, unless you mean it picks up `&nbsp;` or alike (e.g. the UTF-8 equivalent of `&nbsp;`?).

Comment: @mvds No, I meant, what's making sure that when whitespace follows, the regexp stops?

Comment: @Josh the fact that the pattern will only match anything (`[]+`) except (`^`) whitespace etc. (`\\s<`)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to match a specific format, i.e. only the http:// links, a regex is overkill. Just use string functions and loop over your urls testing their length. If you want to get fancy, use `explode()` and `array_walk()`

```
if (strlen($url) > 27) {
  echo substr($url, 0, 27) . '...';
}
else {
  echo $url;
}
```

Comment: I'm parsing long blocks of text that was originally from user input, so I need regex.

Comment: Define *parsing*. I'm not convinced on the *need* to use a regex.

Comment: @Jason McCreary I presume Josh means that the URLs in question are in a larger body of text like a comment or forum post, and they aren't isolated strings in an array.

Comment: @banzaimonkey, @Josh - so use `split()` to break them into an array as noted. Regular Expressions do not have logic to perform replacements based on pattern length. Therefore, you could not do this with a single expression. You should be open to the limits of the technology in question and when something else is appropriate. Too many people think regexes are the solution to all. While a great tool, this is still not true. Thanks for the downvote though.

Comment: @Jason McCreary `split()` is a deprecated function, and is itself based on regex.

Comment: Fair, use `explode()`. The take away is that regular expressions alone can not solve your problem in one go. Furthermore, your regular expression doesn't *parse* or *validate* the URLs. In the end, if you look at the other PHP answer provided, at it's core it is still using string functions to handle the logic you require. Looping over the URLs and using string functions is the way to go.

Comment: And ultimately, I'll agree with you there. Of course, you'll inevitably need to have some sort of regex.

Comment: Goddamn StackOverflow. I wanted to undo the downvote. Would you mind doing a superfluous edit so I can do so?

Comment: @Josh, I updated my answer to reflect the usage of `explode()`. Don't get me wrong, I love Regular Expressions. But they are not the right tool here unless you are parsing or validating the individual URLs. I appreciate the removal of the downvote. I would suggest being sparring with them. You can put some active members of this community off by using them prematurely.

Comment: @Jason McCreary Point very well taken. I was a little too quick on the draw there. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for display in an HTML page, you might consider using CSS to style it with an ellipsis rather than manually truncating it.

You would use CSS something like this:

```
.cutshort {
    overflow: hidden;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:100%;
}
```

The text would then be truncated on screen and be given an ellipsis, even though the HTML code contained the full string.

This technique is not suited to all cases, but where it works it is an excellent alternative to hacking around with your content before sending it to the user.

One important note: The current version of Firefox browser doesn't display the ellipsis dots. It does still truncate correctly though, so it's not a disaster. All other browsers do show the dots, and hopefully a new version of firefox due soon will add it too.