# Limiting a comment to 250 characters

Tags: php, mysql, css

The table below prints out a comment (`($rowquote["comment"])`)in its entirety.  How could I limit it to 250 characters?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec1quote\">";
while ($rowquote = mysql_fetch_array($resultquote)) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename1quote">"'.stripslashes($rowquote["comment"]).'"</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
 }
echo "</table>";
```

**EDIT:**  I got it to work with `left(comment, 250)` in the query. So I guess  [jensgram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52162/jensgram) should get credit fort the comment he made on someone else's answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate a multibyte String to n chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154220/truncate-a-multibyte-string-to-n-chars) - contains solutions for truncating string with and without respecting word boundaries.

Comment: lol..4 of the exact same answer.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively you could do it at the MySQL end and save a little bandwidth.

```
select substring(comment, 0, 250) as comment
```

instead of

```
select comment
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is working, but it is returning the last 250 characters.  How can I make it take the first 250?

Comment: @John [`LEFT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) will work. Alternatively `SUBSTRING(comment, 0, 250)`.

Comment: Or just define the field comment as varchar(250), if you don't intent to store more data in it.

Comment: I got it to work with left(comment, 250).  So I guess jensgram should get credit fort his answer.

Answer (score 2):

`substr(stripslashes($rowquote["comment"]),0,250)` is the simplest way, but a function to make sure it ends on a space is best, something like:

```
function sort_preview($the_content)
 {
  $display = 250;
    $last = substr($the_content,$display,1);
    if ($last != " ") 
     {
    while ($last != " ") 
     {
      $i=1;
        $display = $display+$i;
        $last = substr($the_content,$display,1);
     }
     }
     $the_content = substr($the_content,0,$display);
     }
     return $the_content;
    }
```

called like sort_preview(stripslashes($rowquote["comment"]),0,250)

Answer (score 1):

`substr(stripslashes($rowquote["comment"]), 0, 250)`

Answer (score 1):

Not one to miss out on a trend, I'll give it a shot, too :)

This will try and find periods or spaces to cut at within a given tolerance, favoring longer texts if more than one qualified cut length exists within tolerance (`$cutZone`).

```
function cutstr($str, $length, $tolerance = 5) {
    $cutZone   = substr($str, $length - $tolerance, 2 * $tolerance);
    $posPeriod = strrpos($cutZone, '.');
    $posSpace  = strrpos($cutZone, ' ');
    $ellipsis  = '&hellip;';

    if (strlen($str) <= $length + $tolerance) {
        // $str is shorter than $length+$tolerance - no cut, no ellipsis
        $posCut   = strlen($str);
        $ellipsis = '';
    } elseif ($posPeriod !== false) {
        // $str has period within tolerance - cut at period
        $posCut = $length - $tolerance + $posPeriod;
    } elseif ($posSpace !== false) {
        // $str has space within tolerance - cut at space
        $posCut = $length - $tolerance + $posSpace;
    } else {
        // Nothing to do - cut word
        $posCut = $length;
    }

    return substr($str, 0, $posCut) . $ellipsis;
}
```

(<strike>[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/7KJlJ)</strike>[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/LkOz3))

*In general, **never** fetch more data from the DB than needed. You can easily just select `LEFT(<column>, <lengt+tolerance>)` from the DB and then perform the cutting on this string.*

---

**Update**
Favoring longer texts.

Answer (score 0):

```
stripslashes(substr($rowquote["comment"],0,250)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
substr(stripslashes($rowquote["comment"]), 0, 250)
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`substring`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) for this

```
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec1quote\">";
while ($rowquote = mysql_fetch_array($resultquote)) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename1quote">"'.substr(stripslashes($rowquote["comment"]),0,250).'"</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: typo mistake it should be 250. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec1quote\">";
while ($rowquote = mysql_fetch_array($resultquote))
{ 
 $temp=stripslashes($rowquote["comment"]);
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td class="sitename1quote">';
 for($loop=0;$loop<250;++$loop)
    echo $temp[$loop];
 echo '</td>';
 echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I think you got the downvote because it's like counting bags of candy in a bowl by counting the individual candies & then estimating how many would make a bag, as opposed to just counting the empty bags.

Answer (score -1):

/* in cakephp use tail like this 
*  String::tail($val['Category']['short_description'],250, array('ellipsis' => '','exact' => false))
*/

((strlen($val['Category']['short_description']) > 250)
    ? $description = String::tail($val['Category']['short_description'],250, array('ellipsis' => '','exact' => false))."..."
    : $description =$val['Category']['short_description']) ."...";