# Wordpress/PHP: Shorten title if title characters are more than 8 characters

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to learn how to shorten a title only if it is over 8 characters long. If it is longer than 8 characters, then echo the first 8 characters and put an ellipse after it.

Here is how I am getting the title:

`<?php echo $post->post_title ?>`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This will be a great learning lesson for me so I can replicate this in the future, so again any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

    if (strlen($post->post_title) > 8)
       echo substr($post->post_title, 0, 8) . ' ...';
    else
       echo $post->post_title;

?>
```

---

Alternatively, if You have the `mbstring` extension is enabled, there's also a shorter way as suggested by [Gordon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438726/wordpress-php-shorten-title-if-title-characters-are-more-than-8-characters/4438884#4438884). If the post's encoding is multibyte, You'd need to use `mbstring` anyway, otherwise characters are counted incorrectly.

```
echo mb_strimwidth($post->title, 0, 8, ' ...');
```

Comment: this looks so, beautiful and elegant. ty so much <3

Comment: @HollerTrain: Initially the argument order of `substr()` was not correct in my answer. It's fixed now.

Comment: using `mb_strimwidth` has the additional benefit that it will yield correct results for multibyte characters like these âãäåæçèéêë. Also note that I've used an actual ellipsis `…` instead of three dots `...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mb_strimwidth`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php)

```
echo mb_strimwidth('Your Title', 0, 8, '…');
```

If you want to truncate with respect to word boundaries, see

- [Truncate a multibyte String to n chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154220/truncate-a-multibyte-string-to-n-chars)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in plugin because if you change the theme the changes will be lost

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
$maxlength = 8;
if (strlen($post->post_title) > $maxlength)
       echo substr($post->post_title, 0, $maxlength) . ' ...';
    else
       echo $post->post_title;
```

So by now you no need to change max char in all the line of code.

Thanks.