# Get the first five sentences from the text

Tags: php

Tell me, please, how on PHP to get the first five sentences from the text below?

> Cicero famously orated against his! Political opponent Lucius Sergius Catilina. Погода сегодня хорошая!
>
> Occasionally the first Oration against Catiline is taken for type specimens: quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra? Quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet? Cicero writing letters. Or maybe not.

Comment: Could you please show us what you have tried? How to define a SENTENCE? Should it be end with ".", "!" or "?" ? Think again and do some experiment first.

Comment: I tried to pull the sentence into an array through regular expressions (with function preg_match), but I could not do it.

Comment: `preg_match` returns true or false but it can't return any index or length. If you want to substring the sentence, you need an index and length.

Comment: preg_match has a third parameter, where the result is written

Comment: >> [Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692047/php-get-first-two-sentences-of-a-text)

Comment: [For you reference](https://www.stockeasymoney.com/ns2/test/SqlTest03.php). I did an example for you. Check it if it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how well this will suit your needs, but in the manual for explode there is a "multiexplode" function.

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

$text = "Cicero famously orated against his! Political opponent Lucius Sergius Catilina. Погода сегодня хорошая!

Occasionally the first Oration against Catiline is taken for type specimens: quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra? Quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet? Cicero writing letters. Or maybe not.";

$exploded = multiexplode(array(".", "!", "?"),$text);

print_r(array_slice($exploded,0,5));
```

Then I use array_slice to get the first five items in the array.

Answer (score -1):

It's kind of hard to parse with the non-english characters and the vague definition of a sentence, but the below code should do the tweak. Maybe with a few minor tweaks. It was originally found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10378802/5988467) as Mr. Blue commented above. I've tested a few times and works quite well.

```
Function stripSentence($Text, $Number) {
        $Stripped = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',strip_tags($Text));
        $Sentences = preg_split('/(\.|\?|\!)(\s)/',$Stripped);
        If (COUNT($Sentences) <= $Number) {
            Return $Stripped;
        } Else {
            $Stop = 0;
            ForEach($Sentences AS $i => $Sentence) {
                $Stop += StrLen($Sentence);
                If ($i >= $Number - 1) {
                    Break;
                }
            }
            $Stop += ($Number * 2);
            Return Trim(SubStr($Stripped, 0, $Stop));
        }
    }
```