# Implement Dots After a Certain Limit

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Truncate a multibyte String to n chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154220/truncate-a-multibyte-string-to-n-chars)

Hye guys,

So here's what I need to do. I want dots to appears after a sentence crosses a certain number of words in PHP.

Ex - This is a lazy brown fox.

Now if the words are more than 7 chars -

it should be like

This is..

Comment: `words` or `characters`?

Comment: See http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/truncate/

Answer (score 1):

```
$txt = "test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7";
$txtArr = explode(" ",$txt);
$cut = 3;//cut after 3 words

$txtArr[$cut] = "...";
$arrReady = (array_slice($txtArr,0,$cut+1));

print implode(" ",$arrReady);
```

OR Characters:

```
$text = "some words test lala papa";
print substr($text,0,20)."...";
```

Comment: works pefectly, but I don't want it to cut after three words...I want it to cut after 20 characters. Is that possible?

Comment: @sarthak - I edit my post, please click on the V near my answer if it helps you