# Wordpress – Display page content before read more without using a loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Confusing title, I know. Let me explain.

Currently, I have this little guy set up in my Wordpress theme:

```
<?php 
    $id=7; 
    $post = get_post($id); 
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
    echo $content;  
?>
```

What this does is it displays the content from a certain page of my choice.

Works great! Bravo! Fantastic! The only problem is that I'd like to only show the content before the read more-tag, not ALL of it. And that is where I'm at a loss.

My research (incessant googling, cursing and hammering om my keyboard) has lead me to understand that I could achieve this within a loop. But as I am only going to display the one page that seems a bit redundant.

Also, I'd rather not use the_excerpt as that means the end user won't be able to change the content later on.

Thanks for reading and I hope you can help! Cheerio!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the excerpt not being changable, but if you're looking for a basic WP truncation method see my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219795/truncating-text-in-php

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But the way I need this to be changeable is from within the Admin-section. My client isn't exactly that tech-savvy and won't be able to go into the theme files to change things like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the WordPress function `get_extended($post_content)` to retreive text in content before the `<!--more-->` tag.

For example:

```
$id=7; 
$post = get_post($id); 
$content_arr = get_extended($post->post_content);
echo apply_filters('the_content', $content_arr['main']);
```

Answer (score 0):

By studying the array returned by the `get_extended()` function, I discovered that:

- **If the  tag has been defined** in the post, then:

  - `$content_arr['main']` matches the text BEFORE the `<!--more-->` tag
  - `$content_arr['extended']` matches the text AFTER the `<!--more-->` tag
- **Otherwise**:

  - `$content_arr['main']` matches the entire text of the post
  - `$content_arr['extended']` is empty

*Please note: This behavior differs significantly from what is reported in the documentation. Yet in my WordPress installations I have verified this behavior. This occurs whether the Settings > Reading > "For each post in a feed, include" setting is set to Full text or Excerpt*

For this reason, **the solution I would propose is the following**:

```
$content_arr = get_extended( $post->post_content );
if( !empty($content_arr['extended']) )
{
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $content_arr['main'] );
}
```