# Set character limit of PHP echoed item from JSON within loop

Tags: php, json

I am pulling some data from a JSON source in a PHP loop and want to character limit/restrict one of the data nodes I render. I have used:

```
<?php echo $character['description'] = substr($character['description'],0,250).'...'; ?>
```

But this means each time the loop is called and the next set of results are echoed - the number of limited characters increases... Is there a way to get ALL 'description' strings to be capped to 250 characters with a '...' added after?

loop code is:

```
<?php foreach ($characters as $character) : ?>

<p class="description"><?php echo $character['description']; ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncating Text in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219795/truncating-text-in-php)

Comment: are you saying that the total amount of the descriptions need to be up to 250 or that each has a lenght of 250?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I cannot see why this wouldn't work:

```
<?php foreach ($characters as $character) : ?>

<p class="description"><?php echo substr($character['description'], 0, 250); ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

?

Comment: Basically, the $character['description'] array value should be reset in each iteration of the loop. So I cannot see why my edited version wouldn't work.

Comment: What I mean is that $character always contains the value at the current index of $characters (which is being iterated in the foreach loop). So that should neither "get more or less" during the looping.

Comment: OK.. your code works fine... issue was some nested HTML markup inside the fetched 'description' string from JSON... that was messing things up!

Comment: Great to hear :)