# Wordpress Title PHP Wordwrap

Tags: php, wordpress, word-wrap

I want php to count the characters in my Wordpress post title and if it exceeds 50, insert a break before the word that the 50th character falls in.

For this, I think [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) is the best option?

I am using the following code in my template and it is just echoing the title without inserting the break. Any ideas?

```
<?php
$text = the_title_attribute();
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 50, "<br />\n");
echo $newtext;
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate a multibyte String to n chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154220/truncate-a-multibyte-string-to-n-chars)

Comment: to get the abstract, you use `the_excerpt()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out - I needed to use get_the_title(); instead.

Working code:

```
<?php
$text = get_the_title();
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 50, "<br />\n");
echo $newtext;
?>
```

Comment: This is known to anyone who looks up the function in the WP Codex, which I don't think you did. WP has functions that echo out the value or return the value, you were using the wrong one. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference

Comment: I did, I just chose the wrong one.